# Night cycle object not going smootly when object instantiated

Tags: unity

Hello so I'm adding night cycle to my game it's going smoothly for object except the instantiated one
[image]
[image]

as you can see that is a different color on it.

so here the script for night cycle:

```cs
 public GameObject ca1, ca2, ca3, ca4, ca5, ca6;

 void Update()
    {
        if (_GameManager.instance.isStarted)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (timer >= maxTime)
            {
                GenerateObstacle();

                if (_GameManager.instance.score >= 450)
                {
                    if (_GameManager.instance.score % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        GenerateBuwungObstacle();
                    }

                    if (_GameManager.instance.score >= 3000)
                    {
                        if (_GameManager.instance.score % 5 == 0)
                        {
                            GeneratedMeteorObs();
                        }
                    }
                }

                timer = 0;
            }

            if (_GameManager.instance.score % 200 == 0 && activeFade == null && activeFadeObjectClouds == null)
            {

                fadeToBlack = !fadeToBlack;

                Color colorCactusObs = fadeToBlack ? Color.white : Color.gray;

                activeFadeObjectCactus = StartCoroutine(ObjectCactusFadeTo(colorCactusObs));

            }
        }
    }
   

   // for generating the cactus
  public void GenerateObstacle()
    {
        choosedObstacle = Random.Range(0, Obstacles.Length);
        GameObject obstacle = Instantiate(Obstacles[choosedObstacle]);
    }

  IEnumerator ObjectCactusFadeTo(Color destination)
    {
        Color start1 = ca1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
        Color start2 = ca1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
        Color start3 = ca3.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
        Color start4 = ca4.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
        Color start5 = ca5.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
        Color start6 = ca6.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;

        for (float t = 0; t < 1f; t += (Time.deltaTime / fadeSpeed) * 2)
        {
            ca1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.Lerp(start1, destination, t);
            ca2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.Lerp(start2, destination, t);
            ca3.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.Lerp(start3, destination, t);
            ca4.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.Lerp(start4, destination, t);
            ca5.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.Lerp(start5, destination, t);
            ca6.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.Lerp(start6, destination, t);

            yield return null;
        }

        ca1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = destination;
        ca2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = destination;
        ca3.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = destination;
        ca4.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = destination;
        ca5.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = destination;
        ca6.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = destination;

        activeFadeObjectCactus = null;
    }
```

I already try with for loop in the `object cactus fade` but still not smooth

Comment: `ca1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color` try not to call the GetComponent in a loop but only once, save the reference and use that.

Comment: is it good when using tag dor it?@Zibelas

Comment: but the problem is this game object is instantiated. @Zibelas

Comment: WRT only calling `GetComponent` once, you should call it once and keep a local reference... `private SpriteRenderer renderer;` ... `renderer = ca1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()` As to your question, sorry, no I can't see which colour difference you're referring to?

Comment: @Basic sorry don't understand, there a color difference the first gray the first one white, like as you can see at my 'ienumerator' its should lerping smooth till the end like 0 to 1 vice versa, the problem when new game object spawned the last game object stop to 0.6 or not to end